# I have 2 raspi on the same LAN, How one of them have to pick up a picture from the other

Tags: networking, mount, share

There are answers on this theme but too complicated...as I need only that, that one of the Raspi pick up everyday the picture (temperature graphs) made by the other.
What is the simplest way to do that?
Thank you for the help.
The 2 RASPIS are on the same LAN (Ethernet)

Comment: Do you have experience with SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can either transfer them via scp:

```
# Copy the file "foobar.txt" from a remote host to the local host
scp your_username@remoteip:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

more examples [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

OR you can just set up a http server with python: 
go to your directory where the picture is saved and run this command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This starts a Webserver on port 8000 and you can access the image from the second pi via `http://remoteip:8000/image.jpg`

if you want to start the server at boot, put this in /etc/rc.local:

```
pushd /path/you/want/to/serve; python -m SimpleHTTPServer; popd
```

and then there's the possibility to set up a SMB/NFS/AFP share and grab the file by mounting the share on the other pi. I'm sure you will find some good tutorials when you search for this topic ;)

Comment: The first solution is the simplest and it works but I am asked for my password. Is there a way to avoid it as this command is part of a script.

Comment: google for 'SSH Key Auth' to get info about how this is done, you essentially copy the public key (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_*.pub) from your connecting pi to the serving pi's list of authorized keys (~/.ssh/authorized_keys).